# Change colour of \ac{} in text?

Tags: color

I am trying to change the colour of the inline citations of the acronyms package, but cant figure it out.

I want to have everything in the main text that's in `\ac{}` to be a different colour.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, What is meant with "main text"?

Comment: Does something like `\renewcommand{\acsfont}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}` do what you want? (It's a little unclear what you want, given Jasper's question.)